# Using identical aura:ids

Tags: aura

Is it okay to have two identical `aura:ids` when only one of them is shown at a time? Will there be any problems accessing the shown input using the `component.find`?

```
   <aura:if isTrue="{!(v.currentFlow == 'ACTIVATION')}">
       <p><lightning:input type="date" aura:id="ActivationDate" label="{!$Label.c.enterActivationDate}"/></p>
   </aura:if>

   <aura:if isTrue="{!(v.currentFlow != 'ACTIVATION')}">
       <p><lightning:input type="date" aura:id="ActivationDate" label="{!$Label.c.enterActivationDate}"/></p>
   </aura:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed. Component's `find` will return either `undefined` (no values), an object (one value), or a list (two or more values). There's a small bug that I'm not sure was ever fixed where changing multiple items like this might result in `find` returning a list consisting of a single element, so you may need to prepare for that by checking if there's a `length` attribute before using the results from `find`.